# What updates are needed to JSON to make field visible in clickable Tile view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, multiline-text-field, tiles

I have a column, Notes (multiple lines of plain text), which is visible in the Gallery view but not in the clickable Tile view. How do I make the Notes field visible in Tile view?

Gallery view JSON

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json"
}
```

Tile view JSON

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 337,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation",
          "href": "[$Link]"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight sp-card-imagePreviewBackground"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', 'none', '')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "[$Cover]",
                          "title": "[$Cover.desc]",
                          "class": "sp-card-imagePreview"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "svg",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "preserveAspectRatio": "none",
                          "viewBox": "0 0 210 105",
                          "class": "sp-card-defaultImage ms-bgColor-themeLighter"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path1",
                              "d": "M0 25.7896L126.5 53.8817L96 105H0V25.7896Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path2",
                              "d": "M96 105L158.7 0H204C207.314 0 210 2.68629 210 6V105H96Z"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "svg",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay",
                          "viewBox": "0 0 40 40"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path1",
                              "d": "M 4 4 H 37 V 37 H 4 L 4 4"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path2",
                              "d": "M24.17 21.151L21.66 24.741L17.54 19.191C17.3322 18.914 17.0062 18.751 16.66 18.751C16.3137 18.751 15.9877 18.914 15.78 19.191L9.20997 28.051C8.97126 28.3786 8.93818 28.813 9.12453 29.173C9.31088 29.533 9.68465 29.7567 10.09 29.751H29.91C30.3085 29.7562 30.6769 29.5396 30.866 29.1887C31.0551 28.8378 31.0335 28.411 30.81 28.081L26 21.151C25.7991 20.8407 25.4546 20.6533 25.085 20.6533C24.7153 20.6533 24.3709 20.8407 24.17 21.151Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path3",
                              "d": "M28 15.751C29.3807 15.751 30.5 14.6317 30.5 13.251C30.5 11.8703 29.3807 10.751 28 10.751C26.6193 10.751 25.5 11.8703 25.5 13.251C25.5 14.6317 26.6193 15.751 28 15.751Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path4",
                              "d": "M4.5 37.251H35.5C36.3284 37.251 37 36.5794 37 35.751V4.75098C37 3.92255 36.3284 3.25098 35.5 3.25098H4.5C3.67157 3.25098 3 3.92255 3 4.75098V35.751C3 36.5794 3.67157 37.251 4.5 37.251ZM4 4.75098C4 4.47483 4.22386 4.25098 4.5 4.25098H35.5C35.7761 4.25098 36 4.47483 36 4.75098V35.751C36 36.0271 35.7761 36.251 35.5 36.251H4.5C4.22386 36.251 4 36.0271 4 35.751V4.75098Z"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using custom JSON? If not, try selecting your column in "Card designer" available in SharePoint by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research and testing, please select the `Notes column` in `Card Designer`:

[image]

Please select the `Plain text`:

[image]

Here is my JSON code and test result, you can refer to it:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 393,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation",
          "href": "[$Link]"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight sp-card-imagePreviewBackground"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', 'none', '')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "[$Cover]",
                          "title": "[$Cover.desc]",
                          "class": "sp-card-imagePreview"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "svg",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "preserveAspectRatio": "none",
                          "viewBox": "0 0 210 105",
                          "class": "sp-card-defaultImage ms-bgColor-themeLighter"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path1",
                              "d": "M0 25.7896L126.5 53.8817L96 105H0V25.7896Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImage-path2",
                              "d": "M96 105L158.7 0H204C207.314 0 210 2.68629 210 6V105H96Z"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "svg",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay",
                          "viewBox": "0 0 40 40"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path1",
                              "d": "M 4 4 H 37 V 37 H 4 L 4 4"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path2",
                              "d": "M24.17 21.151L21.66 24.741L17.54 19.191C17.3322 18.914 17.0062 18.751 16.66 18.751C16.3137 18.751 15.9877 18.914 15.78 19.191L9.20997 28.051C8.97126 28.3786 8.93818 28.813 9.12453 29.173C9.31088 29.533 9.68465 29.7567 10.09 29.751H29.91C30.3085 29.7562 30.6769 29.5396 30.866 29.1887C31.0551 28.8378 31.0335 28.411 30.81 28.081L26 21.151C25.7991 20.8407 25.4546 20.6533 25.085 20.6533C24.7153 20.6533 24.3709 20.8407 24.17 21.151Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path3",
                              "d": "M28 15.751C29.3807 15.751 30.5 14.6317 30.5 13.251C30.5 11.8703 29.3807 10.751 28 10.751C26.6193 10.751 25.5 11.8703 25.5 13.251C25.5 14.6317 26.6193 15.751 28 15.751Z"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "path",
                            "attributes": {
                              "id": "sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path4",
                              "d": "M4.5 37.251H35.5C36.3284 37.251 37 36.5794 37 35.751V4.75098C37 3.92255 36.3284 3.25098 35.5 3.25098H4.5C3.67157 3.25098 3 3.92255 3 4.75098V35.751C3 36.5794 3.67157 37.251 4.5 37.251ZM4 4.75098C4 4.47483 4.22386 4.25098 4.5 4.25098H35.5C35.7761 4.25098 36 4.47483 36 4.75098V35.751C36 36.0271 35.7761 36.251 35.5 36.251H4.5C4.22386 36.251 4 36.0271 4 35.751V4.75098Z"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Title.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Notes.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Notes]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content  sp-card-multiline"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Notes] == '', '–', [$Notes])",
                "style": {
                  "-webkit-line-clamp": "2",
                  "height": "40px"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Link.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "a",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Link]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-urlContent  sp-card-keyboard-focusable",
                  "href": "[$Link]",
                  "target": "=if ([$Link] == '', '', '_blank')"
                },
                "style": {
                  "pointer-events": "=if ([$Link] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
                  "text-decoration": "=if ([$Link] == '', 'none', 'auto')"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Link.desc] == '', '–', [$Link.desc])"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.